# Cannot install Office 2003 Professional on a machine which formerly had 2003 Basic

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2003

I have a problem with one of our PCs. I've inherited this PC and it's always had MS Office basic on it; the time has come to install our Access application on it, so I'm trying to install Office Professional 2003, the problem I have is the installer says the license key is invalid; I can only assume this is down to the fact that the PC used to have Office Basic installed. I've deleted the registration keys for the OFFICE11 section of the registry, but am still getting the problem... Any suggestions as to how to kill any trace of the old install would be appreciated - its' no longer showing up in the add/remove programs window.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue.  Microsoft has the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility to deal with this.  [Installer Cleanup](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B290301)

Comment: Thanks Dave - it didn't do the trick.. Found another way around it in the end - most annoying though :(

Comment: @Paul -- please post your own answer with whatever you did to fix it so we know what answered the question.